# Cordova call function when NOT from resume

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am listening for `deviceready` and `resume` events in Cordova.

In my `deviceready` I only want to call a function, if the app is **not** starting from a `resume`.

I.e. can I achieve the below?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
  doOnlyWhenNotFromResume();
}

function onResume(event) {
  doOnlyWhenFromResume(event);
}
```

Cordova version 7.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean flag to avoid the `doOnlyWhenNotFromResume()` function from being called on resume. If you set this flag when a `pause` event happens it should work because after pausing the app and "warm-starting" the app again the resume event is triggered.

Declare this variable in some scope where its accessible for your functions:

```
var isResume = false;
```

And modify your existing code as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

  if (!isResume) {
    doOnlyWhenNotFromResume();
  }
}

function onResume(event) {
  doOnlyWhenFromResume(event);
}

function onPause(event) {
  isResume = true;
}
```